# Getting stacktrace of the test method in VS and C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, integration-testing

I have a solution that contains heaps of integration tests. These tests are run on schedule. I need to produce report from those tests. After all the test has been run. I have been able to collect all the information in the XML but what i really want is

:
Get the method name of the test which is currently running, and if there is any error get the error "**stack trace**"

How am i able to achieve this using c# and Visual Studio? Will really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Which framework are you using for your integration tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your logging method to use [Environment.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx).  This should allow your results to contain stack traces of the point in your test code that is failing.

Code from MSDN:

```
// Sample for the Environment.StackTrace property 
using System.  

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: '{0}'", Environment.StackTrace);
    }
}
/*
This example produces the following results:

StackTrace: '   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e)
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Sample.Main()'
*/
```

Comment: I can't imagine its so simple to do this. Took me a lot of time was going deeper in to something else. Thanks Matt!!